# Differences in displaying images on a JLabel using different IDEs, Eclipse vs JGRASP

Tags: java, eclipse, image, swing, embedded-resource

So i've recently decided to up my game and try to learn how to use the fabled Eclipse IDE. So far so good, I love it for many reasons, but i've encountered one simple issue.

I added an image to a JLabel using the `ImageIcon` format like I used to when I was learning Java using the JGRASP IDE, only the problem is, the image won't display at all in Eclipse. There is just an empty panel. When I switch over to JGRASP, despite the fact that the image is far too large for the display area, it definitely displays at least partially, unlike in Eclipse.

My question is, why could this be? I have the .jpg file located in the src folder of my project, so that isn't the issue(I used the same folder when I loaded the project into JGRASP). Do I need to define a pathway when using Eclipse or is there something else I could be missing?

Anyways, here is my code so far, bare bones as it is. This is just a fun project that i'm working on for practice to keep GUIs fresh in my mind and to try some new things:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * @author Pat
 *
 */

public class GameProject extends JFrame
{

    private Font f1 = new Font("ComicSans", Font.BOLD, 40);
    private Font f2 = new Font("ComicSans", Font.BOLD, 32);
    private Font f3 = new Font("ComicSans", Font.BOLD, 18);

    private ImageIcon gamer = new ImageIcon("Game_Collage.jpg");

    public GameProject() 
    {
        setTitle("Welcome To Fuego's Game Rater");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,0));

        JPanel introPnl = new JPanel();
        JPanel gamePicPnl = new JPanel();
        JPanel rbPnl = new JPanel();

        JTextArea welcomeLbl = new JTextArea("Welcome to my game rater. Here, you will select a"
                                    + " favorite genre of video game based on several categories."
                                    + " Once selected, you will be prompted to input your favorite"
                                    + " title from that specific genre.", 3, 40);
        welcomeLbl.setFont(f3);
        welcomeLbl.setForeground(Color.blue);
        welcomeLbl.setLineWrap(true);
        welcomeLbl.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        welcomeLbl.setOpaque(false);
        welcomeLbl.setEditable(false);

        JLabel gamePic = new JLabel("");
        gamePic.setIcon(gamer);


        //Radio Buttons
        JRadioButton rpg = new JRadioButton("RPG");
        JRadioButton arpg = new JRadioButton("Action RPG");
        JRadioButton fps = new JRadioButton("First Person Shooter");
        JRadioButton puzzle = new JRadioButton("Puzzle");
        JRadioButton actAdv = new JRadioButton("Action/Adventure");
        JRadioButton sideScrl = new JRadioButton("Side Scrollers");
        JRadioButton strategy = new JRadioButton("Strategy/RTS");

        //Button group
        ButtonGroup bGroup = new ButtonGroup();

        bGroup.add(rpg);
        bGroup.add(arpg);
        bGroup.add(fps);
        bGroup.add(puzzle);
        bGroup.add(actAdv);
        bGroup.add(sideScrl);
        bGroup.add(strategy);

        //Adding items to intro panel
        introPnl.add(welcomeLbl);

        //Adding item to gamePic panel
        gamePicPnl.add(gamePic);

        //Adding items to Radio Button panel
        rbPnl.add(rpg);
        rbPnl.add(arpg);
        rbPnl.add(fps);
        rbPnl.add(puzzle);
        rbPnl.add(actAdv);
        rbPnl.add(sideScrl);
        rbPnl.add(strategy);

        //Adding items to layout
        add(introPnl);
        add(gamePicPnl);
        add(rbPnl);

        //Pack and display window
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }   


        /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new GameProject();

    }

}
```

Comment: ImageIcon(Strung) assumes that the Strung reference points to a file in the file system. Where is image file stored?

Comment: Stored in the src folder of my project in Eclipse as stated above.

Comment: Make a directory called resources at the same level as the sec directory in your project. Place you image file there, the use ImageIcon(GameProject.class.getResource("/Game_Collage.jpg")) or ImageIcon(GameProject.class.getResource("/resources/Game_Collage.jpg"))

Comment: Added that line right after I created the ImageIcon, but i'm getting all sorts of errors, such as needing a return type, "class" identifier expected ect. I'm sure I didn't do something correctly :( It's a start though I appreciate your help.

Comment: Your code will display the image if the program is launched from the src directory (which JGrasp does). ANd won't work if it's loaded from anywhere else (which is the case in Eclipse). The image file should be loaded from the classpath, as MadProgrammer explains.

Comment: I copied that line of code verbatim and i'm getting all sorts of errors. Should I place this in the constructor? I currently have it declared globally. I removed the creation of the ImageIcon as well and replaced that with the line madProgrammer posted above. I created a new folder called resources as instructed and placed the image file inside said folder. what else could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I placed that line inside the constructor and it removed several errors, minus one. "The method ImageIcon(URL) is undefined for the type GameProject." Do I need to create an external method for this?

Comment: Fixed. Just needed to do some tinkering. Thanks for the replies guys.